Converting Zoom Video Raw data into video frames
I’m working on a macOS application using the Zoom Video SDK, and as per the SDK documentation, the user video is received in the ZMVideoSDKYUVRawDataI420 format from onRawDataFrameReceived which is mention on here(https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/macos/video/#render-video) However, the documentation doesn’t explain how to convert this I420 raw data into video frames for display in a view. How to achieve this and show the user video in a view?
I am using following code to convert it into frames
func renderVideoFrame(_ frame: ZMVideoSDKYUVRawDataI420) {
    let width = Int(frame.streamWidth)
    let height = Int(frame.streamHeight)
    let yPlane = frame.yBuffer
    let uPlane = frame.uBuffer
    let vPlane = frame.vBuffer
    guard let rgbData = convertYUVtoRGB(yPlane: yPlane, uPlane: uPlane, vPlane: vPlane, width: width, height: height) else {
        return
    }
    
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: rgbData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: width * 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)


    if let cgImage = context?.makeImage() {
        let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.viewController.displayImage(nsImage: nsImage)
        }
    }
}

func convertYUVtoRGB(yPlane: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?, uPlane: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?, vPlane: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?, width: Int, height: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? {
    guard let yPlane = yPlane, let uPlane = uPlane, let vPlane = vPlane else {
        return nil
    }

    let rgbSize = width * height * 4
    let rgbData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: rgbSize)

    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: height) { y in
        for x in stride(from: 0, to: width, by: 2) {
            let yIndex = y * width + x

            // Calculate chroma indices for the subsampled U and V planes
            let chromaX = x / 2
            let chromaY = y / 2
            let uIndex = chromaY * (width / 2) + chromaX
            let vIndex = uIndex

            // Fetch U, V values
            let U = Int(UInt8(bitPattern: uPlane[uIndex])) - 128
            let V = Int(UInt8(bitPattern: vPlane[vIndex])) - 128

            // Precompute UV components
            let v1 = 5727 * V
            let uv1 = -(1617 * U) - (2378 * V)
            let u1 = 8324 * U

            // Process even pixel
            var Y = Int(UInt8(bitPattern: yPlane[yIndex])) << 12
            var R = (Y + v1) >> 12
            var G = (Y + uv1) >> 12
            var B = (Y + u1) >> 12

            // Clamp RGB values to valid range [0, 255]
            R = min(max(R, 0), 255)
            G = min(max(G, 0), 255)
            B = min(max(B, 0), 255)

            // Store the RGB values in the output buffer
            var rgbIndex = yIndex * 4
            rgbData[rgbIndex] = UInt8(R)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 1] = UInt8(G)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 2] = UInt8(B)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 3] = 0  // Alpha value

            // Process odd pixel
            Y = Int(UInt8(bitPattern: yPlane[yIndex + 1])) << 12
            R = (Y + v1) >> 12
            G = (Y + uv1) >> 12
            B = (Y + u1) >> 12

            // Clamp RGB values to valid range [0, 255]
            R = min(max(R, 0), 255)
            G = min(max(G, 0), 255)
            B = min(max(B, 0), 255)

            // Store the RGB values in the output buffer
            rgbIndex = (yIndex + 1) * 4
            rgbData[rgbIndex] = UInt8(R)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 1] = UInt8(G)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 2] = UInt8(B)
            rgbData[rgbIndex + 3] = 0  // Alpha value
        }
    }

    return rgbData
}


"However, the documentation doesn’t explain how to convert this I420 raw data into video frames for display in a view. How to achieve this and show the user video in a view?" - I'm not a Swift/macOS developer, but if this were any other platform the answer is "you aren't meant to" because that would be incredibly slow and inefficient: instead you'd pipe the video-stream directly to some OS+GPU-managed surface where everything happens within the GPU (with the GPU's accelerated video decoding to boot).
